# How to set one value in a two dimensional javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to set a single value in a two dimensional array, but its not working.

Consider the following code taken from the many examples on the subject:

```
// create a 3x3 array with -1 in every position:
let a = new Array(3).fill(new Array(3).fill(-1))
console.log(`a: ${JSON.stringify(a)}`)
a[1][2] = 0
console.log(`a: ${JSON.stringify(a)}`)
```

The output is as follows:

```
a: [[-1,-1,-1],[-1,-1,-1],[-1,-1,-1]]
a: [[-1,-1,0],[-1,-1,0],[-1,-1,0]]
```

As we can see, instead of setting a single cell, it as actually set 3 positions in the array to 0, i.e. it sets [0][2] and [1][2] and [2][2] = 0.  Very odd.

I tried this:

```
let a = new Array(3).fill(new Array(3).fill(-1))
console.log(`a: ${JSON.stringify(a)}`)
a[1,2] = 0
console.log(`a: ${JSON.stringify(a)}`)
```

Which gives the even stranger result:

```
a: [[-1,-1,-1],[-1,-1,-1],[-1,-1,-1]]
a: [[-1,-1,-1],[-1,-1,-1],0]
```

Am I going crazy, or does javascript not support setting a value in a 2 dimensional array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First question**

That's because you fill the outer array with the same subarray! `a[0]`, `a[1]` and `a[2]` are all the same array! Because in JS objects (including arrays) are passed around using their references! What `array.fill` does is taking a parameter (in this case a reference to an array) and assigns it to every item in the array. It's like this:

```
var sub = new Array(3);
sub.fill(-1);

var a = [];
a[0] = sub;
a[1] = sub;
a[2] = sub;

a[0][1] = 0;

console.log(sub); // changed too
```

Because here is what `array.fill` is doing:

```
var a = new Array(10);
a.fill(Math.random()); 

console.log(a);   // not 10 different random numbers, but the same random number is assigned to the whole array
```

**Second question**

It has nothing to do with arrays. It's a [**comma operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) like the one used in the for loops (for example), to group expressions into one and returning the value of the last:

```
console.log((1, 2)); // 2
console.log((1, 5, "last")); // last
console.log((1, 5, 5 * 11 + 10)); // 65

// the parens are used to distinguish the comma operator from the parameter separator
```

So `a[1, 2]` is the same as `a[2]` because the value of `1, 2` is `2`!

Comment: @JohnLittle I added some explanation for your second question too! Just saw it! You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You are filling the array with same reference **new Array(3).fill(-1)** in all three rows and therefore any change to one will be reflected everywhere.

Try:

```
var a = new Array(n);
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  a[i] = new Array(n);
}
//where n = 3 for your case.
```